# iOS build error: Certificate doesn't match profile: The default keychain doesn't have an identity matching

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to build my app on [PhoneGap Build](http://build.phonegap.com). Build works with Development certificate but not with Distribution certificate.
I get this error:

```
Error - Certificate doesn't match profile: The default keychain doesn't have an identity matching
```

I already tried to re-generate a new provisioning file (`.mobileprovision`) from my Apple Developer panel, as said here
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2183665

but it doesn't work. I don't know how to solve. Some helps?

**EDIT: here a screenshot of my certificates**

[image: reenshot of my certificates]

Answer (score 1):

are you creating your distribution certificate with the same identity (installed of your computer?) 
this identity is for distribution?
In your keychain check that when you select the certificate (before to create mobileprovisioning), the id of identity is the same.... 
in keychain you can search your identity which will be of the type:  "iPhone distribution: yourIdentity (K84TO6G85C -> alpha numeric string)"

Comment: Hi Alessio. I have only one identity on my Mac; yes the identity is for Distribution. I added a screenshot of my Keychain, could you check it? I think it's ok. Please let me know.thanks

Comment: ok, i don't have skills on Phonegap but i think that when you try to build app you can choose your identity.
So, your mobileprovisioning is associated to your distribution identity? for check this, you can use "iPhone Configuration Utility" and check identity associated to all mobileprovisioning installed on your mac.
I think that your distribution mobileprovisioning has another identity...

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message. My problem was that I uploaded the Developers and not the Distribution Certificate in PhoneGap. After replacing that in PhoneGap it worked.